# HTML Table dynamic height

Tags: css, html, pdf, svg

My problem is that I have several image, SVG and PDF files which I want to display in a dynamic grid. For this I've been using a table like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
        <tr>  
              <td width="35%"> 
                  <div class="work">
                        <a href="w1.html">
                            <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="media" alt=""/>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="work_title">
                                    <h1>WORK IMAGE 1</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td> 
                <td width="35%"> 
                  <div class="work">
                        <a href="w2.html" height=100%>
                            <img src="img/work2.jpg" class="media" alt=""/>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="work_title">
                                    <h1>WORK IMAGE 2</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td> 
                <td width="30%" height=100%>
                        <div class="work">
                            <a href="work3.html">
                                <embed src="work3.pdf#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0" width=100% height=100% type='application/pdf'>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <div class="work_title">
                                        <h1>WORK PDF 3</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                </td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The CSS for this part is like this:

```
.main .work{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The good part is that images automatically scale to their maximum width, and change the table height to the height they reached this way.

However the PDF and SVG files don't even try it. For some reason they are stuck at a 150pt height. When I inspect the elements in the browser, I get the following:

- The td (table cell), that contains the PDF or SVG file in an example has the height of 238pt.
- Its child is a "work" div, which already has only 153 height, although in the CSS it's clearly stated, that is should be 100%.

I've tried looking a lot of things up, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. I split up the images/pdf from the caption but still has the same affect that you wanted with the click.

```css
    table .work {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: table-row;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
```

```html
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="35%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="w1.html">
            <img src="http://webresizer.com/images2/bird1_before.jpg" width="100%" class="media" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="35%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="w2.html" height="100%">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/potofgold.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="30%" height="100%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="work3.html">
            <embed src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/example.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="100%"
              type='application/pdf'></embed>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="35%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="w1.html">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="work_title">
                <h1>WORK IMAGE 1</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="35%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="w2.html" height="100%">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="work_title">
                <h1>WORK IMAGE 2</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="30%" height="100%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="work3.html">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="work_title">
                <h1>WORK PDF 3</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Let me know if this helps or if you need more.

Comment: Thank you! I changed almost everything to the same settings you suggested, however I left in the captions (they are needed for a transition effect), and it still worked when I left the captions in.

Comment: Perfect! Good luck!